# Mouse pointer lags in QT5 app on TI Sitara

Tags: qt, embedded, yocto, texas-instruments, cortex-a8

We are using TI Sitara AM33 system on chip with 600 Mhz clock and 256 Mb ram.
OS is OE Yocto v2.1 Krogoth, kernel 4.4.19. Video driver - DRM/KSM

We are having issues with mouse performance.

I have made a little vedio to demonstrate the effect:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5dRDGzhcnn0

Note how mouse pointer is moving smoothly on the blank area of the window and lags over at controls. It's as if it is going through jelly. If you have more controls on the window, mouse becomes so laggy, it's unusable. CPU load is minimal though.

There could be no error in the example app in the vedio - we created a blank QT Widget project, put the controls on the form and that's it, it is not doing anything else at all.

Has anyone seen such mouse issues?

Comment: Qt5, I hope, means a GPU involved, so CPU load doesn't matter a lot. BTW with controls there is a lot of work to do to repaint areas an recalculate objects compared to the blank area. So can be a computational matter on GPU side. Moreover can also be a problem of RAM reserved to graphics: swapping structures increases lags.

Comment: Yes, this is QT5. I don't know how to profile a GPU on embedded system, but if i run "top" it tells me CPU load is arounf 40% and 0 Mb of swap used.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using an X server, then you need to check what platform plugin is Qt using on your platform. Perhaps that plugin is broken or not the best choice in your situation.

Your application is also very unlikely to use GPU in any capacity other than to composite the windows (if at all), so the CPU load being low is rather telling.

It seems as if the event dispatch system on your platform was very slow the more widgets there are. This is unlikely to have much to do with the graphics side of things. In a process of elimination perhaps you could first benchmark the performance of synchronization primitives (`QBasicMutex` and `QMutex`) and atomic integers and pointers to ensure that they are configured correctly for your platform.

Comment: I tied disabling all the controls i.e. buttons will be inactive and hence unclickable. This improves things dramatically. I would blame the graphics for slow painting the button hover over animation, but the cusor is slow even when hoved over radio buttons and check boxes. Perhaps then, you are right and the system is somehow very slow to respond to the hover event itself, even though there is none defined?

Comment: First of all, prepare a debug *and* release build of Qt, both with debug information. Then run the *release* build and check its performance. Only if it performs poorly, run it under a profiler and see exactly where it spends its time.